# Upload Dokka Docs to maven with gitlab pages

Tags: android, maven, gradle, jekyll, kotlin-dokka

I have a multi module project, which I have used dokka to generate KDocs/Javadocs for each of the libraries(modules). I have a private gitlab with multiple projects and I want to use gitlab pages to somehow upload all of these generated `index.html` pages for all of my module and packages.

My question is does this require that I merge the all the documentation from each of the modules into a single `index.html` file or can I achieve the same goal of having all the project documentation at a single location with each module in the project owning its own `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you use the Dokka Gradle or Maven plugin. In case your project is Gradle multi module, you can probably use the `subprojects` configuration option to have separate documentations and one merged. Such functionality is not supported in Maven, but I guess you can configure dokka in each module and then configure dokka in the root project manually (pass all the `sourceRoots` and `classpaths` from subprojects there)